# How to get props details on get Api request with VUE 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4, routeparams

Hello i'm starting learning VUE 3 with the router and i don't understand how to retrieve data from id ? please

My console log always return undefined ?

Here my code, you can also see on the codesanbox link if you wants too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-with-rick-and-morty-api-qdfe12?file=/src/main.js

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "CharacterById",
  props: ["id", "name", "species", "status"],
  data() {
    return {
      character: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${this.id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.character = res.data.results;
        console.log("GET DETAIL", this.character);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Because there's no `results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are getting data inside `res.data` not the `res.data.results`
[image]

Comment: Wow thanks, but for all characters i have to call the array results.
Why for one character we don't need to call it anymore please ?
Is it because we get his **id** and it works ? maybe

Comment: @ThomasChalanson I just checked their doc and their data response structure is like that. When you call an API to get all the characters, the data are inside the "results" key but when you call an API to get a single character, it just returns an object of character.
The response for all characters https://prnt.sc/9hiViPq_PPRx
The response for a single character https://prnt.sc/cE78hpS5m2WJ
see the difference, there is no `results` key in a single. its just an object

Comment: ok right, I should have read the doc ^_^